# Create conda environment from file without default packages

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to create conda environment from a file `environment.yml`.

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

This works but I want to avoid installing the *default packages*.

I found flag *--no-default-packages* but this applies only to `conda create` and this command doesn't accept the `environment.yml` file.

Is there a way how to use `environment.yml` and NOT install default packages?

**EDIT:**
My ultimate goal is to create environment which could be packaged (or the *site-packages* of the environment) as lambda for AWS. But it seems conda is installing way too much with every package.

E.g.:

```
bash-4.2# conda create --name test
bash-4.2# source activate test
(test) bash-4.2# conda install networkx
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /root/miniconda3/envs/test:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    certifi:    2016.2.28-py36_0
    decorator:  4.1.2-py36_0
    networkx:   1.11-py36_0
    openssl:    1.0.2l-0
    pip:        9.0.1-py36_1
    python:     3.6.2-0
    readline:   6.2-2
    setuptools: 36.4.0-py36_1
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0
    tk:         8.5.18-0
    wheel:      0.29.0-py36_0
    xz:         5.2.3-0
    zlib:       1.2.11-0
```

Why is this command installing *Python*, *pip* and other packages? Are these real dependencies of *networkx*?

On the other hand if I do `pip install -t . networkx` it installs just the *networkx* just as expected.

Comment: What do you mean by "default packages"? Can you be more specific about why they're included in the environment - a dependency on another package, pip, etc.

Comment: @darthbith: clarified my question, thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way how to use `environment.yml` and NOT install default packages?*

Only the `conda create` command uses the `create_default_packages`. The `conda env create` already ignores the `create_default_packages` configuration by design.

For example, I just checked adding `git` to default packages, then created an environment from a YAML with `wget` as only dependency, and it did not install `git`.

---

> *Why is this command installing Python, pip and other packages? Are these real dependencies of `networkx`?*

Yes, those are the actual dependencies. They may be dependencies of dependencies (and so on), but they are what is needed to install and run `networkx` according to the package builders.

---

> *...if I do `pip install -t . networkx` it installs just the `networkx`*

The comparison to `pip install` is misleading. The `pip install` CLI command itself is an entry point defined by the `pip` module. An equivalent command would be:

```
python -m pip install networkx
```

which makes explicit the fact that one cannot install `networkx` without already having `python` and `pip`.

Keep in mind that Conda was designed from the outset to provide broader support for non-Python dependencies and thus facilitate more independence from the hosts system-level libraries. Hence, you should expect there to be more dependencies, especially ones that would never appear in a system Python using PyPI only.

Answer (score 0):

These packages are part of the [Anaconda metapackage](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/packages.html#anaconda-metapackage) which defines the core Anaconda dependencies.